# What are the routes of an ubuntu repository?

Tags: repository, 19.04

In my university there are the repositories of ubuntu 19.04, however, I need help to configure the urls that I must add in the file "sources.list".I wrote this in the file "sources.list":

```
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] http://ubuntu.reduniv.edu.cu/UBUNTU/ubuntu/ disco main universe multiverse restricted 
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] http://ubuntu.reduniv.edu.cu/UBUNTU/ubuntu/ disco-security main universe multiverse restricted 
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] http://ubuntu.reduniv.edu.cu/UBUNTU/ubuntu/ disco-updates main universe multiverse restricted 
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] http://ubuntu.reduniv.edu.cu/UBUNTU/ubuntu/ disco-proposed main universe multiverse restricted
```

Comment: I'm confused, this shouldn't really be needed typically, why do you need to do this?

Comment: In the sources.list file are the addresses that by default the system takes to update from the official repositories but in my university we can not access these repositories. The repositories to which we have accesses are others that are located in a national network.